# How to deal with the situation where coauthors use different bibitem names in their .bib files

Tags: bibtex, collaboration

My coauthor and I have very large `.bib` file which we using since several years.

To be precise, each of us, uses a global `.bib` file for all of our manuscripts.

Unfortunately, the names of some bibitems in mine and in my coauthor's `.bib` file are different.

Since we have used some of these bibitem's names in our previous TeX files, it is difficult for each of us to use the bibitem name of the other one.

What are the ways to solve this problem?

**Edit.**

To be precise, assume that this is our common file:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\cite{einstein1935}

\bibliography{C:/Users/admin/mybibtexfile}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\end{document}
```

This is my bibtex file with other hundreds of entries:

```
@article{einstein1935,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
  author={Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
  journal={Physical review},
  volume={47},
  number={10},
  pages={777},
  year={1935},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

This is my coauthor bibtex file ith other hundreds of entries:

```
@article{einstein,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
  author={Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
  journal={Physical review},
  volume={47},
  number={10},
  pages={777},
  year={1935},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Well, what exactly is the difference? Can you show us one of yours bib entry and the same of your coauthor? How do you build the bibliography? Can you show us a short tex code building your bibliography? Is your tex code the same your coauthor uses?

Comment: You can use multiple bib files in a single document. You'd just need to agree on the references, such that the same paper referenced from two files does not get duplicate references. Afterwards both parties are responsible for putting the missing references from the other file in their own database.

Comment: There may be several sophisticated tricks you could use that i do not know.  But the basic point it seems to me is that when BibTeX encounters one reference called einstein1935 and one called einstein then it *ought* to treat them as distinct even if the data under the two names are identical.  You really should synchronize the entry names in your .bib files.

Answer (score 2):

For an "perfect" collaboration you should define a naming sheme for all of your together used bib entries.

That could for example be something like `author-year-label` with always lower case letters) like `einstein-1935` or `einstein-1935-d` if you have for entries of Einstein in the year 1935. If you do not like the `-` omit them: `einstein1935d` (not so easy to be read I think ...). Think about using all author names (or let us say the first three) if the article/book etc. has more than one author. Then your used name changed to `einsteinPodolskyRosen-1935` for example (capital letter to see easy the start of the next author name) ...

To make sure both of you are using the same bib file and both of you can edit and add new entries use something like github to store your together used bib file. Then both of you can work on their documents using the same bib file with no double bib entries with different names ...

Bib entry:

```
@article{einstein-1935,
  title={Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete?},
  author={Einstein, Albert and Podolsky, Boris and Rosen, Nathan},
  journal={Physical review},
  volume={47},
  number={10},
  pages={777},
  year={1935},
  publisher={APS}
}
```

and is to be cited for example with `\cite[p. 35]{einstein-1935}` ...

Depending on your used bibliography management system you can try to combine both bib files and run your bibliography management system to find duplicates and to create a logical naming system for all bib entries.  As far as I know `bibtool` can locate duplicates and delete the duplicates, if it can do a proper renaming I do not know, sorry (windows user, `bibtool` is not running on my system).